# Variable changing value without changing it in the code

Tags: java, variables, biginteger, division

I am working on a custom numeric class for big numbers like BigInteger. I have to create this method where it finds the prime factorization of a given number. The problem lies in that method, when I assign the current value of a number and it doesn't find a factorization soon(like after 2 or 3 iterations) the value unexpectedly changes. Here's the code

```
    public ArrayList<String> factors(){
    ArrayList<String> pList = new ArrayList<>();
    FedNumbers in = this;
    FedNumbers d = new FedNumbers("2");
    FedNumbers zero = new FedNumbers("0");
    FedNumbers squared = d.product(d);
    while(d.compareTo(in)<=0){
        System.out.println(in);
        if(in.divideR(d).compareTo(zero)==0){

            pList.add(d.toString());


            in=in.divideQ(d);


        }
        else{
            d.inc();
            squared=d.product(d);
        }
    }
    pList.add(in.toString());

    return pList;

}
```

divideQ is a method that divides and returns the coefficient and divideR one that returns its residue. The squared variable exists because of the assumption that I can found its factorization before sqrt(n). product multiplies two values and returns its result.

Here's the output for in being 161 at the beginning:

161
161
151
141
141
131
121
121
111
111
111
101
[1]

It never enter the iteration, I tried the division with residue and compareTo together in a tester alone and it worked, cant get why the in value changes suddenly after two iterations with no reason to.

That's the in value or the current value that I'm trying to factorize, same thing happens with many other numbers and every time I check its only the in value changing randomly. When I divide and use divideQ or divideR separate or multiply it always works perfectly. Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: You haven't posted `FedNumbers`, but you mention it's like `BigInteger`; is it **immutable**?

Comment: Changed it to non-inmutable now, still persists

Comment: What is the value that 'changes randomly'? You are definitely re-assigning in. Also if FedNumbers is immutable, what are things like `d.inc()` supposed to do?

Comment: Why is the output surprising? The line `in=in.divideQ(d)` reassigns the variable `in` to the result of divideQ, and the output you're printing is `System.out.println(in)`, so I would expect to see the printed value change every few iterations when the first branch of the `if` is followed.

Comment: The in value, for example I wanna know the factors of 161, so they are 7 23 and 1, and it should be there but instead it keeps asking after 7, like 161 goes from 2:6 but instead of staying like that it changes in the second iteration for 151 for absolutely no reason, when I debug it it appears still as 161 I don't know whats going on.

Comment: Edward yeah you are correct, but still there's no reason for the in value to  change as if I were subtracting from it when I'm not even reassigning the value because it doesn't satisfies the conditions.

Comment: Changed the code with the output outside the if, still the same, there's no reason for it to change when it never enters the if.

Comment: `squared` is computed but never used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the source of your problem is here:

```
FedNumbers in = this;
```

I may be wrong, but could it be that you think that this `copies` the current object, i.e., the one for which you call `factors()`, creating `in` as a new object?

This is not so. Copying a reference simply establishes another reference *to the same object*. Throughout `factors`, `this` and `in` refer to the same object.

It should not be too difficult to add a copy constructor to your code.

Comment: I used the toString method to initialize in as if it were a new object, like new FedNumbers(this.toString()) effectively initializing a new one, and the problem still persists

Comment: I isolated the problem and verified that it only happens when I increment the variable d, with d.inc() or with d.sum(one) the in value starts decreasing randomly

Comment: If you want better help than random tips then there's no way around posting the code of FedNumbers, at least so far that methods inc and sum can be read and understood *in full*.

Comment: Found the problem thanks to all of you, it is what you said, I started making all the references to new FedNumbers with the toString() and it worked, thanks

Comment: Good. You still might want to look into a copy constructor, which is bound to be more efficient than the internal-to-string-to-internal detour.